# How can I download "sysinstall" on CentOS7?

Tags: centos, software-installation

My professor has specific instructions in my homework to:

> "use sysinstall to execute the menu system at the the command prompt"

It sounds silly to me because yum is the default package manager on CentOS, so why would he want us to use sysinstall? I have already tried `sudo yum install sysinstall`, but no package was found. So maybe it has a different name and I just can't find it.

Comment: sysinstall utility is used for installing and configuring FreeBSD systems, there must be a confusion about naming...

Comment: That's what I initially thought too, but I didn't think my professor could be that clueless.

Comment: can you tell what is the actual task? what menu system is it about?

Comment: It's not the GUI apparently, since I emailed him about that exact question, but it was lacking in any further instruction. Here's a link to the assignment, if it helps. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B2AHnONH4hfTaVjZaYeJdNAESbjTL0k5)

Comment: you definitely need BSD system to achieve that